# Python, discord.py - search wikipedia with user input

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with Discordpy and WikipediaApi. The bot is supposed to print Wikipedia summary after entering an appropriate sentence: "What is...?" or "Who is...?". So far, it's working well, but the Wikipedia page is defined in the code. I want take a page title as keyword from user, for example, he might ask "What is Microsoft?" or "Who is Elon Musk?" and receive a reply (if a page exists in Wikipedia, of course). I know I should use client.wait_for(), but I feel confused with that, as the input will be a part of longer sentence.

```
import discord
import wikipediaapi

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not (message.author == client.user):
        if (message.mention_everyone == False):
            if (client.user.mentioned_in(message) or isinstance(message.channel, discord.abc.PrivateChannel)):
                async with message.channel.typing():

                    if message.content.startswith('What is') or message.content.startswith('Who is'):
                        wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('pl')
                        page_py = wiki_wiki.page('Elon Musk')  <----- HERE

                        await message.channel.send("Page - Summary: %s" % page_py.summary)

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the wikipedia api? IMO it would be easier in many ways to use the `requests` api to get the source code of the page, if it exists

Comment: I noticed that Wikipedia api is a popular solution and it was not so hard to find how to implement it in my own code. Also, the result on Discord looks as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you're trying to parse it out of every message, you could try just splitting the "command" (`What is`/`Who is`) and take the remainder as the query.

```
if message.content.startswith('What is') or message.content.startswith('Who is'):
    args = message.content.split(" ")  # Split the message based on spaces
    if len(args) > 2:  # Checks if a query was passed, avoids a potential IndexError
        query = " ".join(args[2:])  # Cut out the "What is" part, and join the rest back into a single string with spaces
        wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('pl')
        page_py = wiki_wiki.page(query)
```

I do strongly recommend using the built-in Commands module though, and just making a "Wiki" command. This way, your code would look as follows:

```
@client.command()
async def wiki(ctx, *query):
    if query:  # I'm not sure what the wikipedia api does if you give it an empty string, so this if-statement makes sure something was passed
         query = " ".join(query)  # The rest of the args were passed as a list, so join them back into a string with spaces
         wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('pl')
         page_py = wiki_wiki.page(query)
```

And you can call it in Discord by simply doing `[prefix]wiki elon musk`. In your case, you check if the bot was mentioned to parse commands [which can also be handled with prefixes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when%20mentioned#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or), so you wouldn't lose any functionality on that end (and can add more prefixes if you so wish).

Comment: I decided to not to use cogs and prefix commands, as my bot is a chatbot based on AIML files (so its main role is to have conversations with the user). It was important for me that it can react naturally to certain sentences. I will try you suggestions!